# Array Objects as name of button objects in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an NSMutableArray:

```
myButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"buttonOne", ... ,@"buttonNine",nil];
```

where each object is the name of a button object.

Now, I want to disable all the buttons, using a for loop.

I wrote the following:

```
for (id obj in myButtons)
    [obj setEnabled:NO];
```

but am getting an Error!
Am I doing something Wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you appear to be calling `setEnabled` on an `NSString`, not on a `UIButton`. Either fill your array with the `UIButton` objects, or get the buttons from their string names.

Answer (score 0):

@"buttonOne" is just a string. Didn't you want to add just buttonOne instead (as button-object)?

Answer (score -1):

```
@interface Treasure_PyramidViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;

@implementation Treasure_PyramidViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for(id priyadas in buttons ){
        [priyadas setEnabled:NO];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```